# Differentiable manifold in dimension 1 and its critical point

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, definition

Please, I want to know how to define a differentiable manifold in dimension 1,
and if the circle is a differentiable manifold in dimension $1$, and what is its critical point.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you look at the [Wikipedia article on differentiable manifold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_manifold)?

Comment: I just replace n by 1?

Answer (score 2):

The unit circle $S^1:=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:x^2+y^2=1\}$ endowed with an atlas of *[stereographic projections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection)*
$$x_N:S^1\setminus\{(0,-1)\}\to\mathbb{R},~x_N(x,y):=\left(\frac{x}{1+y}\right)$$
and
$$x_S:S^1\setminus\{(0,1)\}\to\mathbb{R},~x_S(x,y):=\left(\frac{x}{1-y}\right)$$
is an one dimensional differentiable manifold, since the atlas is a differentiable structure (i.e. the domain of the charts $x_N,x_S$ cover $S^1$ and the transition map 
$$x_N\circ x_S^{-1}:x_S(S^1\setminus\{(0,-1)\}\cap S^1\setminus\{(0,1)\})\to x_N(S^1\setminus\{(0,-1)\}\cap S^1\setminus\{(0,1)\})$$
is a diffeomorphism).

Comment: ok, please what is the critical point of S^1 ? thank you

Comment: @Vrouvrou Are you aware of the definition of a critical point? I suppose you need to be more specific, since a critical point is related to a differentiable map between two manifolds.